# Html::error doesn't seems to be working on ajaxValidation or clientsidevalidation

Tags: php, yii2

I have been shifting from yii 1.1 and yii 2.0, and i have to display my attribute error at the top of the form and no inline errors, but finding it hard to so, to achieve my requirement i tried putting below code at the top of my form:

`<?= Html::error($model, 'username',['class'=>'help-block']); ?>`

But it doesn't display any errors on `ajaxValidation` and `clientValidation` while on normal submit and validate it is showing up the error.

Am i doing something wrong or is there an alternative to achieve this or is this missed or left out?

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
'id' => 'login-form',
'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
'enableClientValidation' => false,
'validateOnSubmit' => true,
'validateOnChange' => false,
'validateOnType' => false

]); ?>

//  Error for username attribute here is not showing up, on validating with ajax,
<?= Html::error($model, 'username', array('class' => 'loginerrors help-block')); ?> 
//  how to show the error here..?? In yii 1.1 we simply call $form->error($model, "username") but here there is nothing like it.

<div class="loginForm" id="login1">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="span4 offset4 control-group" id="username_offset">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(); ?> 
            //Not here, it is displaying the error here on ajax validation, by forming divs dynamically.
        </div>
        <div class="span4 control-group">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="span12">

                <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: give full code of form. if possible.

Comment: @gamitg done, updated. Please check.

Comment: Can you post the model's rules too?

Comment: Just in case anyone wondering what happened to this..here you go..
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9700

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get these using the [getErrors()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#getErrors()-detail) function of the ActiveRecord class. For your code you'd want something like so;

```
echo $model->getErrors('username');
```

That would return an array of errors relating to that field. It returns an array even if there is only one error message